# Working with a map of objects in dynamic library: what is the best practice?

Tags: c++, dll, dynamic-library

I have a code built to a dynamic library. The code has a definition of a class, and it is called with a given ID and it either creates an object and puts in in a map with the ID as the key, or it calls the existing object. A minimal example of this is as follows (this particular example is for Windows, for Linux or MacOS only `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` needs to be changed):

```
#include <map>

class myClass {
 public:
  bool flag;
  double a;
  double b;
};

std::map<int,myClass> objectMap;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void myLibrary(
    int id,
    double a,
    double b,
    double* c,
    int* d
    )
{
    objectMap[id].flag = true;
    objectMap[id].a += a;
    objectMap[id].b += b;
    *c = objectMap[id].a + objectMap[id].b;
    *d = objectMap.size();
}
```

Naturally, this has the problem that objects are created and never destroyed.

EDIT:

I cannot really keep track of which objects are not needed anymore because the library is being called by another program that I don't have access to.

I was wondering if there is some way, not that dirty, in which I can erase elements if they have not been accessed for a while.

For example, a dirty way I think that would work for me is to keep track of the time/number of times the library is called and erase all the old objects/the objects have not been used in the last N calls, but that seems pretty ugly.

Is there any common practice for such scenario?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If your caller can call `myLibrary` to add elements, logically, it should also call something else when elements are no longer needed.

Comment: Which objects are you wanting to free? The ones stores in `objectMap`? If you know you don't need an entry anymore, you can `erase` it. Otherwise they'll be destroyed (and the memory freed) when `objectMap` goes out of scope and is destroyed.

Comment: @SergeyA Fair enough, I was nor clear. I am editing it...

Comment: *"I cannot really send a message to say that an object needs to be freed."* - Because.. ? You've created an API that says an object potentially needs to be *added*. It seems a limiting move to not reciprocate that with an API to remove by id as well. So.. what's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: There are several approaches to evicting old/unused values. See [tag:lru] for one. Essentially, you keep a time-of-last-access with each value and periodically evict ones that are either too old, or the oldest one(s) when you've reached your N values.

Comment: If your use-case post-update is as described, your library ultimately must be cognizant of the *when*; as in *when* an item is no longer needed. Assuming you can *guarantee* concluding when that condition flips from still-needed to no-longer-needed, ejection can be accomplished thereafter as a subordinate to the only API you're apparently exposing: the "add/update" operation. That's not trivial, and only you know when/how something falls into the no-longer-needed category. There is no silver bullet to that question.

Comment: If you can erase objects at will without your users losing their data, then perhaps just don't put them in a map in the first place.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks for the suggestion, indeed that is a good starting point.

Comment: @WhozCraig I will try to see if there is a way to get what ids are to be removed and do that with the caller. I understand it would be by far the best way.